# Get original type of an argument passed to ruby script

Tags: ruby

I have this code in `script.rb`:

```
puts ARGV[0].class
```

When I pass an argument to the script like:

```
ruby script.rb 1
```

the `1` seems to be automatically converted to a string because I get `String`. Otherwise, when I do:

```
1.class
```

I get `Fixnum`.

Is there a way to get the original type of an argument passed to the script?

Comment: The `1` *is* a string, just like the other characters in that line.

Comment: What makes you think that `1` passed from the shell is not a string? Are you thinking that it is interpreted as if it were Ruby script (so that `1` becomes a literal for a fixnum)? If so, what do you think about doing `ruby script.rb foo` from the shell? Do you expect `foo` to be interpreted as a method or local variable?

Comment: @sawa no, I would assume, that foo would be a string of course

Comment: @Heisoka what about `ruby script.rb 007` - would you assume the integer `7` or the string `"007"`?

Comment: @Stefan I thought, if I want an explicit string I would just do ruby script.rb "007" and otherwise 007 would be converted to a an integer, if possilble and if not, to a string. But welp, unfortunately this isn't the case.

Comment: you could use `puts eval(ARGV[0]).class ` if you want to evaluate the string as ruby code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, arguments passed into scripts are always strings.

Comment: True, but it's not a limitation specific to Ruby scripts.

Answer (score 1):

> The "1" seems to be automatically converted to a string

No, it is a string from the beginning.

> Is there a way to get the original type of a passed argument?

Yes, you just call `class` on it as you already did, and you will get `String`.

Comment: As I have shown, I want the original type. If you could show, how I get "Fixnum" by passing a number to a script, that would be nice. But I guess @Marek Lipka is right, and they are always strings. Thx

Comment: @Heisoka how would you pass "1" as a `String` to your script? How can the script tell the difference?

Comment: @Heisoka You didn't seem to understand my answer. If you did, you wouldn't have given such comment. "I want the original type" and " how I get Fixnum" are two entirely different things.

Comment: @Stefan I dont know, sorry that I was asking a question

Answer (score 1):

Command-line arguments are always passed as strings and are always separated by space:

```
# script.rb
p ARGV
```

```
$ ruby script.rb foo bar 123 "I'm one arg"
["foo", "bar", "123", "I'm one arg"]
```

This is not a Ruby limitation, it's how the command line interface works. If you write:

```
$ cp script.rb 1.00
```

then the program [cp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_(Unix)) copies the file "script.rb" to the file "1.00" (yes, that's an awful filename, but a valid one). This works because both arguments, `script.rb` and `1.00`, are passed as strings. If *cp* would receive the string `"script.rb"` and the number `1.0` instead (trailing zeros are not necessary), the command would certainly fail.

You cannot alter this behavior, but you can easily *convert* the argument yourself:

```
# script.rb
number = Integer(ARGV[0], 10)
puts number, number.class
```

[`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) is a built-in conversion function. When given a string, it attempts to convert the string to an integer with the given [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix).

```
$ ruby script.rb 123
123
Fixnum
```

It also raises an error if the string is invalid:

```
$ ruby script.rb foo
script.rb:1:in `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "foo" (ArgumentError)
    from script.rb:1:in `<main>'
```